Javascript setTimeout function not working in tests
Essentially, in the onSearch function, when I run tests on my App.tsx, the function passed into setTimeout is not being executed.
I used the debugger to see the call stack and how the code executes and everything was fine until it reached the setTimout function and the function I passed into setTimeout was not executed.  When I put the if statement outside the setTimout, that code gets executed, but when I put it back into setTimeout, it does not execute. I also tried to play around with the time that i pass into the setTimeout function, but that still doesn't work.
I have also checked that in my tests I am indeed pressing the button in order to trigger the OnSearch function, which does indeed get triggered, but once it reaches the setTimout function line, it stops.
Can anyone give me advice on how to fix this issue and have the code inside setTimeout function execute?
Code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./App.css";
import { DisplayUser } from "./components/user";
import { GithubUsersProvider } from "./providers/github-users-provider";
import { User } from "./providers/users-provider";

function App() {
  const githubUsersProvider = new GithubUsersProvider();
  const [queryUser, setQueryUser] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  async function onUserSearch(username: string) {
    try {
      const users = await githubUsersProvider.getUsers(username);
      setUsers(users);
    } catch (e) {
      setUsers([]);

      setError(
        "There was an error retrieving the data: " + (e as Error).message
      );
    }
  }

  function onSearch() {
  console.log('reached before setTimeout') // gets excuted 
    let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (queryUser !== "") {
        onUserSearch(queryUser);
      }
    }, 500);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }
  console.log(queryUser);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {error && <div className="error-message">{error}</div>}
      {!error && (
        <div className="app-content">
          <h1>Github Repository Explorer</h1>
          <div className="input-container">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter a username..."
              value={queryUser}
              onChange={(e) => setQueryUser(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={() => onSearch()}>Search</button>
          </div>

          <main className="user-main">
            {users.map((user) => {
              return (
                <DisplayUser
                  username={user.username}
                  profileUrl={user.profileUrl}
                />
              );
            })}
          </main>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

whilst for the tests:
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import { UserEvent, userEvent } from "@testing-library/user-event";
import App from "../App";
import { StubRepoProvider } from "./stubs/stub-repo-provider";
import { StubUsersProvider } from "./stubs/stub-users-provider";
import { UsersProvider } from "../providers/users-provider";
import { RepoProvider } from "../providers/repo-provider";

describe.only("searching", () => {
  let usersProvider: UsersProvider;
  let repoProvider: RepoProvider;
  let renderResult;
  let queryByText;
  let input: HTMLInputElement;
  let user: UserEvent;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    usersProvider = new StubUsersProvider();
    repoProvider = new StubRepoProvider();
    user = userEvent.setup(); //?
    renderResult = render(<App />);
    input = renderResult.getByPlaceholderText("Enter a username...");
    queryByText = renderResult.queryByText;
  });

  describe("should return results even when 1 letter is entered", () => {
    let searchButton;
    beforeEach(async () => {
      searchButton = queryByText("Search");
      jest.spyOn(usersProvider, "getUsers").mockResolvedValue([
        {
          username: "j",
          profileUrl: "test.com",
        },
      ]);

      await user.type(input, "j");
    });
    test("The provider should be called as expected when search button clicked", async () => {
      await user.click(searchButton);

      expect(usersProvider.getUsers).toHaveBeenCalledWith("j");
    });

    
  });
});

